# How does json4s use DefaultFormats to serialize and deserialize json?

Tags: scala, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to understand how [json4s](http://json4s.org/) serializes and deserializes json, specifically how it uses formats. Are there any online references that show how json4s uses the `DefaultFormats` to serialize and deserialize json? The official json4s website doesn't shed much light on this.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultFormats` is a provided implementation of `Formats` trait.

You can see how it used in `Extraction.decompose` and `Extraction.extract` methods (json4s uses these methods for serialization/deserialization).

`Extraction.extract` uses `Extraction.convert`:

```
private[this] def convert(key: String, target: ScalaType, formats: Formats): Any = {
  val targetType = target.erasure
  targetType match {
    case tt if tt == classOf[String] => key
    case tt if tt == classOf[Symbol] => Symbol(key)
    case tt if tt == classOf[Int] => key.toInt
    case tt if tt == classOf[JavaInteger] => JavaInteger.valueOf(key.toInt)
    case tt if tt == classOf[BigInt] => key.toInt
    case tt if tt == classOf[Long] => key.toLong
    case tt if tt == classOf[JavaLong] => JavaLong.valueOf(key.toLong)
    case tt if tt == classOf[Short] => key.toShort
    case tt if tt == classOf[JavaShort] => JavaShort.valueOf(key.toShort)
    case tt if tt == classOf[Date] => formatDate(key, formats)
    case tt if tt == classOf[Timestamp] => formatTimestamp(key, formats)
    case _ =>
      val deserializer = formats.customKeyDeserializer(formats)
      val typeInfo = TypeInfo(targetType, None)
      if(deserializer.isDefinedAt((typeInfo, key))) {
        deserializer((typeInfo, key))
      } else {
        fail("Do not know how to deserialize key of type " + targetType + ". Consider implementing a CustomKeyDeserializer.")
      }
  }
}
```

So, json4s tries to find in `Formats` custom deserializer for all unknown types.

`Extraction.decompose` uses `Extraction.decomposeObject` under the hood, where json4s try to serialize all types by a custom serializer:

```
if (formats.customSerializer(formats).isDefinedAt(a)) {
  current addJValue formats.customSerializer(formats)(a)
}
```